# Why do database checks not raise errors in rspec, but do raise errors in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, factory-bot

I'm writing a blog app using rails 5.0.2, ruby 2.4.0, and postgresql 9.6.2. I wrote some tests using Rspec to check that the postgres check constraints are stopping invalid data from being saved to the database. The null constraints pass in Rspec, but the length check constraints fail. However, when I try to save the same data in rails console, I get errors.

I wrote the following tests using Rspec for database checks:

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

  describe 'database checks' do

    context 'without email' do
      let :user { build :user, email: nil }

      it { expect {user.save validate: false}.to raise_error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid }
    end

    context 'without name' do
      let :user { build :user, name: nil }

      it { expect {user.save validate: false}.to raise_error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid}
    end

    context 'without encrypted password' do
      let :user { build :user, encrypted_password: nil }

      it { expect {user.save validate: false}.to raise_error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid }
    end

    context 'empty email' do
      let :user { build :user, email: '' }

      it { expect {user.save validate: false}.to raise_error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid }
    end

    context 'empty name' do
      let :user { build :user, name: ''}

      it { expect {user.save validate: false}.to raise_error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid }
    end
  end
end
```

User factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, do
    email "test@example.com"
    password "test password"
    name "Test"
    created_at { 5.seconds.ago }
    updated_at { DateTime.now }
    description "Test description
  end
end
```

User table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    email character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying NOT NULL,
    encrypted_password character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying NOT NULL,
    reset_password_token character varying,
    reset_password_sent_at timestamp without time zone,
    remember_created_at timestamp without time zone,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    description text,
    CONSTRAINT email_length_check CHECK ((length((email)::text) > 0)) NO INHERIT,
    CONSTRAINT name_length_check CHECK ((length((name)::text) > 0)) NO INHERIT
);
```

Rspec output:

```
Randomized with seed 21829
F.F..

Failures:

  1) User database checks empty email should raise ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
     Failure/Error: it { expect {user.save validate: false}.to raise_error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid }
       expected ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid but nothing was raised
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User database checks empty name should raise ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
     Failure/Error: it { expect {user.save validate: false}.to raise_error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid }
       expected ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid but nothing was raised
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.41576 seconds (files took 14.93 seconds to load)
5 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:28 # User database checks empty email should raise ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:34 # User database checks empty name should raise ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Randomized with seed 21829
```

Rails console output:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 11864
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.2)
[1] pry(main)> user = FactoryGirl.build :user, email: ''
=> #<User id: nil, email: "", name: "Test", created_at: "2017-04-09 00:19:37", updated_at: "2017-04-09 00:19:42", description: "Test description">
[2] pry(main)> user.save validate: false
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.9ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("encrypted_password", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$UCKPTyuQyfgyWibv3mlv4OFavF2nLtGwFhHvYJMmCepwevJhSja2u"], ["name", "Test"], ["created_at", 2017-04-09 00:19:37 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-04-09 00:19:42 UTC], ["description", "Test description"]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::CheckViolation: ERROR:  new row for relation "users" violates check constraint "email_length_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, , $2a$11$UCKPTyuQyfgyWibv3mlv4OFavF2nLtGwFhHvYJMmCepwevJhSja2u, null, null, null, Test, 2017-04-09 00:19:37.826153, 2017-04-09 00:19:42.826772, Test description).
: INSERT INTO "users" ("encrypted_password", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
from /Users/edgarlepe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
[3] pry(main)> user = FactoryGirl.build :user, name: ''
=> #<User id: nil, email: "test@example.com", name: "", created_at: "2017-04-09 00:20:21", updated_at: "2017-04-09 00:20:26", description: "Test description">
[4] pry(main)> user.save validate: false
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.9ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "test@example.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$gmMGIjSKycqLmOybtxuWAee.OMHdyktzM2ZeR3ZawHEGkYk1SlMki"], ["name", ""], ["created_at", 2017-04-09 00:20:21 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-04-09 00:20:26 UTC], ["description", "Test description"]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::CheckViolation: ERROR:  new row for relation "users" violates check constraint "name_length_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (10, test@example.com, $2a$11$gmMGIjSKycqLmOybtxuWAee.OMHdyktzM2ZeR3ZawHEGkYk1SlMki, null, null, null, , 2017-04-09 00:20:21.010989, 2017-04-09 00:20:26.011515, Test description).
: INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "description") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"
from /Users/edgarlepe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
```

User model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :articles
end
```

Comment: Are you using the exact same schema on your test database? Have you tried the rails console in the test environment with `rails c -e test`

Comment: May you show code of user model

Comment: @Iceman It looks like I was not. I tried `rails c -e test` and saving an invalid user didn't throw any errors. How do I get the development and test databases to be the same?

Comment: @IlyaLavrov I added the code for the user model.

Comment: try `rake db:test:prepare` to set test database to the same schema as development database

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I'm still having the same problem. Although I have `config.active_record.schema_format :sql` in `config/application.rb`, `rake db:migrate` generates `db/schema.rb` instead of `db/structure.sql`.
I dropped the databases and created new ones by running `rake db:drop` and `rake db:create`. When I ran `rake db:migrate`, I got a `db/schema.rb` instead of a `db/structure.sql`. I'm thinking that when my test database is loaded, it is loaded from the `db/schema.rb` without the check constraints.

Comment: That's exactly what's going on